# Lynxmotion AL5D arm interfacing with MoveIt

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, arduino, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have one lynxmotion AL5D arm and i want to use that with ROS mainly with moveIt . any one help me how i can do this ? even i have my own Urdf file that i can visualize in Rviz . if any one have any link or knowledge please share with me .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280140/lynxmotion-al5d-arm-interfacing-with-moveit/) by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-01**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/211557/connect-lynxmotion-al5d-arm-to-ros/ is still relevant, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now i have a Github repo
Thanks all

here is the github repo :-
https://github.com/ibtisamtauhidi/Lynx-AL5X-Controller

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-01**:
Well, I don't think that this is an answer :-) But happy you figured something out. Please share what this is so others might benefit...

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-01**:
yeah done sir

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-01**:
If you put quotes around a URL then a link doesn't get rendered. If you just put the URL in with nothing around it a link does get rendered.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-02**:
@jayess someone from ROS community say that to me so that link not disappear after changing URL

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-02**:
I don't understand your comment, but if you look at *every* instance in which you put quotes around a link that link renders as text not as a link. I removed the `'` from this one as a demonstration.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-02**:
@jayess thanks alot

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-02**:
No problem

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-02**:
@jayess may i get your Email for more information ?